# How to extract a particular string from a file in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a column named filepath and the contents are as below:

```
/data/sudi/tmp/3680170/nn/asset_category/output
/user/vandu/jobhistory/753/109539/skill-metadata.har/_masterindex
/data/new/copy/253002002635638.wav
/data/old/tub/tki/businesseffectivedate=2017-12-05
/data/abc/def/2017-12-07/253002002635637.xml
/data/cde/bbf/test.db/execution_gdspm0102017-12-05.txt
```

I want to extract all the file extensions after the period (`.`) and give the count of files with different file formats..

Comment: @user9314128 was my answer of any help?

Answer (score 0):

There's a `regexp_extract` function [in Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF). Pattern would be something like `^.*\/?.*\.([^\/\.]*)$`. [Click here](https://regex101.com/r/ySg5tK/1) to test the regex.

```
SELECT count(*), regexp_extract(path_column, '^.*\/?.*\.([^\/\.]*)$', 1) as ext
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY ext
```